# How do attempt static method get attached to the Auth class in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-authentication

I learnt that there is a [`Auth::attempt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#remembering-users) static method in Laravel.

But when I dig into the underlying source code, I could only find the method in [SessionGuard.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L354) instead of [Auth.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.php).

How did the method get "attached" to the `Auth` class?

Comment: `Auth` is a facade. You can learn about its functionality [here in laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades#how-facades-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the method that `attempt` is being called on in a default setup as `SessionGuard` is what the 'web' auth guard is using. In the [Facade Class Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades#facade-class-reference) you will see that `Auth` is referring to the `AuthManager`, you can look at the source of that to see the dynamic call to the driver that is actually used via magic methods.

`Auth Facade -> AuthManager -> Driver -> attempt()`

The magic `__callStatic` method on `Facade`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php#L253

The magic `__call` method on `AuthManager`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php#L305

Comment: I found that the SessionGuard instance were created by the createSessionDriver() method, but I cannot find any code calling that method. How does the method work?

Comment: the `resolve` method of the `AuthManager` is going to create the driver based on the configuration ... you will see something like this in there: `$driverMethod = 'create'.ucfirst($config['driver']).'Driver';` ... so `createSessionDriver` ... then `return $this->{$driverMethod}($name, $config);`

Comment: I understand it now. Thx.

Comment: the `guard` method is what will call `resolve` btw ... `guard` is called by `__call` .... `guard -> resolve -> createSessionDriver`